# Phonegap: How to customize toolbar?

Tags: iphone, cordova

Is anyone familiar with how to customize the ToolBar in phonegap beyond the default setting? I understand there is the option to use black-opaque or black-translucent, but can I go beyond that? For instance using another color, or a gradient?

If this is not innately possible in phonegap, how is it done in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C, the UIToolbar has a `tintColor` property.  Assuming PhoneGap does not already publish an interface to set this, it should be fairly easy to add one for flat colors.

The `tintColor` affects, among other things, the gradient used.  Using a totally custom gradient would be more difficult.